# Neo4j query - performance assistance needed

Tags: neo4j

Here's another Neo4j newbie question....

I am playing with a very naive and simple graph.
The following query is supposed to return clusters, defined so that each friend in the cluster KNOWS all other friends in the cluster. I have limited the cluster size to 4 in this example, and added the last few ANDs to make the results unique (so I will not get A,B,C and A,C,B):

```
MATCH (me { name: 'MyName' }), (f1), (f2), (f3), (f4)
WHERE (me)-[:KNOWS]->(f1)-[:KNOWS]->(me)
AND (f2)-[:KNOWS]->(f1)-[:KNOWS]->(f2)
AND (f2)-[:KNOWS]->(me)-[:KNOWS]->(f2)
AND (f3)-[:KNOWS]->(me)-[:KNOWS]->(f3)
AND (f3)-[:KNOWS]->(f1)-[:KNOWS]->(f3)
AND (f3)-[:KNOWS]->(f2)-[:KNOWS]->(f3)
AND (f4)-[:KNOWS]->(me)-[:KNOWS]->(f4)
AND (f4)-[:KNOWS]->(f1)-[:KNOWS]->(f4)
AND (f4)-[:KNOWS]->(f2)-[:KNOWS]->(f4)
AND (f4)-[:KNOWS]->(f3)-[:KNOWS]->(f4)
AND f1.name < f2.name
AND f2.name < f3.name
AND f3.name < f4.name
RETURN DISTINCT f1.name, f2.name, f3.name, f4.name
```

Now the query works just fine in terms of data correctness, but I have noticed it takes well over a second to complete.
Are those normal response times for Neo4j? Is there a more efficient way to perform the same query?
Now, I'm running the Neo4j server on my laptop, but on the other hand, I only have 15 nodes in the DB.... I can only imagine what would happen when the DB grows...

Answer (score 2):

You might try moving the path definitions to the `MATCH`.  I'm pretty sure the only time you should use path definitions in `WHERE` is when you're doing `NOT(path)`.

```
MATCH (me { name: 'MyName' })-[:KNOWS]->(f1)-[:KNOWS]->(me),
(f2)-[:KNOWS]->(f1)-[:KNOWS]->(f2),
(f2)-[:KNOWS]->(me)-[:KNOWS]->(f2),
(f3)-[:KNOWS]->(me)-[:KNOWS]->(f3),
(f3)-[:KNOWS]->(f1)-[:KNOWS]->(f3),
(f3)-[:KNOWS]->(f2)-[:KNOWS]->(f3),
(f4)-[:KNOWS]->(me)-[:KNOWS]->(f4),
(f4)-[:KNOWS]->(f1)-[:KNOWS]->(f4),
(f4)-[:KNOWS]->(f2)-[:KNOWS]->(f4),
(f4)-[:KNOWS]->(f3)-[:KNOWS]->(f4)
WHERE f1.name < f2.name AND f2.name < f3.name AND f3.name < f4.name
RETURN DISTINCT f1.name, f2.name, f3.name, f4.name
```

It also makes the query a bit cleaner too, I think

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work faster indeed. Although, strangely, I sometime get this strange behavior where the query takes a long time to complete the first time I run it for a given start node. The subsequent queries runs very fast (<500ms). I guess/assume this has something to do with caching, but I wonder whether I can do anything to avoid that behavior (in many cases the app will execute this query only once)

Comment: It's probably because you're not using an index.  If you use labels (Neo4j version 2.0+) you can create an index on the `name` property for the label and you should get a much faster query finding that start node.

Answer (score 1):

I think a different way of finding clusters is much better than this approach, e.g. taking a start point and following all nodes using variable length paths to the end of the cluster, sort the cluster-nodes by id and make sure to have each list of nodes is unique.

Comment: Thanks, do you have any example to get me starting? it doesn't have to be fully functional example, just something to get me started...